# Pass function as param and execute custom function?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my android app:

```
  suspend fun getTraidersList(): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // some common methods
            try {
                val response: Response<List<Trader>> = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
             //  some common methods
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
               // some comon methods
            }
        }

        suspend fun executeTraderOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String): TransportResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // some common methods
            try {
               val response: Response<Void> = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
             //  some common methods
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
               // some comon methods
            }
}
```

As you can see I has 2 methods that has many common methods. I want to extract this common methods in separate method.
I want to pass function as param to my_common_method. 
Is it possible to do smt like this in Kotlin?

```
suspend fun my_common_method(fun some_custom_function) {
            // some common methods
            try {
                val response: Response<*> = some_custom_function()
             //  some common methods
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
               // some comon methods
            }
        }
```

Maybe has better solution?

In `getTraidersList()` the function `some_custom_function` is `getTraidersList()`. And in `executeTraderOperation` the function `some_custom_function` is `executeTraderOperation`.
Is it possible in Kotlin?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 2):

what you could do is use a higher-order function:

```
suspend fun my_common_method(block: suspend () -> Response<TransportResponse>) {
            // some common methods
            try {
                val response = block()
             //  some common methods
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
               // some comon methods
            }
        }
```

then you just call `my_common_method {getTraidersList() }`